# problem while using enabled csrf_protection with Facebook Application

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, csrf

Hello everyone,
       I have implemented a basic Facebook Application with codeigniter.  Its work fine until the csrf_protection=false (i.e Cross Site Request Forgery is disabled).  But when i enable Cross Site Request Forgery protection as csrf_protection=true (i.e Cross Site Request Forgery is enabled).  It doesn't work.  So how can i run my app with csrf_protection=TRUE.

Thanks in advance,
  aby

Comment: thanks @i_forget, i have editted my question

Answer (score 0):

When you build a request to facebook, you ussually have uri like these...

```
// If you want to enable CSRF, you can build some unique state and save it to session
$csrf_state = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE));
$this->session->set_userdata('fb_csrf_state', $csrf_state);
$dialog_url = 'http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" 
                    . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($redirect_url)
                    . "&scope=publish_stream,user_about_me,user_birthday" 
                    . "&state="
                    . $csrf_state;
```

If you enabled CSRF, then ussualy you need to save above $crsf_state in session, before redirecting user to Facebook, then inspecting with the returned request from Facebook (along side with $_GET['code'])

```
 // Then you can inspect the CSRF state
 if($this->session->userdata('fb_csrf_state') == $_REQUEST['state'])
 {
     // This request valid, process...
 }
 else
 {
     // CSRF not valid, give user a warning
     echo "You may be a CSRF victim, please try again";
 }
```